# PHP/MYSQL echo totals counts from query

Tags: php, mysql, count, echo

I have run a query using COUNT(id) as a way to sum up the number of rows with a given id.  I now want to print that number.  Since there are many ids, I need to print it many times.  I think each pageid/count(id) is its own row of the table but maybe I am wrong.  Here is the gist of the code (apologies for using mysql_query):

```
$sql = "SELECT pageid, COUNT(id) FROM views 
GROUP BY pageid 
ORDER BY COUNT(id)"

$res = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
  echo $row['pageid'];
  echo $row['count(id)'];
}
```

except the last line is not working.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array indexes are case-sensitive. Since you're selecting `COUNT(id)`, you should use `$row['COUNT(id)']` and not `$row['count(id)']`.

Alternatively, you can give the count an alias.

```
$sql = "SELECT pageid, COUNT(id) pagecount FROM views 
GROUP BY pageid 
ORDER BY COUNT(id)"
```

With the above, you could use `$row['pagecount']`.

Comment: This worked.  Thanks to everyone who gave similar answers.  Someone downvoted my question probably because I did not accept answer immediately. I could not work on this until today.  It would be nice if you would remove downvote, however you are.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT pageid, COUNT(id) as tot_id FROM views 
GROUP BY pageid 
ORDER BY id"
...
echo $row['tot_id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You must capitalize count as it's set as COUNT in the sql Call.